# Calculate the derivative of $f(x)=\int_x^{x^2}\tan(x+y)\,dy$ on the open interval $(0,\frac{\pi}{4})$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

This appears to be a chain rule question, but I'm struggling with the setup. My attempt is as follows:

> Let $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,
>
> $F(u,v)=\int_u^{u^2}$tan$(v+y)dy$,
>
> $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$,
>
> and $u(x)=(u(x),v(x))=(x,x)$.

Then writing $f(x)=(F\circ u)(x)$ allows for use of the chain rule:

> $D(F\circ u)(x)=DF(u(x),v(x))Du(x)=\left[\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\mbox{ }\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\right]\begin{bmatrix}u'(x)\\v'(x)\end{bmatrix}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}(u(x))u'(x)+\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}(u(x))v'(x)$

Then by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,

> $\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\int_u^{u^2}tan(v+y)dy=\mbox{tan}(v+u)=\mbox{tan}(x+x)=\mbox{tan(2x)}$

And similarly,

> $\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\int_u^{u^2}\mbox{tan}(v+y)dy=\int_u^{u^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\mbox{tan}(v+y)dy=\int_x^{x^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\mbox{tan}(x+y)dy=\int_x^{x^2}\mbox{sec}^2(x+y)dy$

However at this point, I'm relatively convinced I'm making a major mistake, either with my entire substitution or with the way I'm handling the boundaries. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule):

\begin{align}
f'(x) &= 2x\tan(x+x^2) - \tan(2x) + \int_x^{x^2} \frac{dy}{\cos^2(x+y)}\\
&= 2x\tan(x+x^2) - \tan(2x)+ \tan(x+y)\Big|_x^{x^2}\\
&= (2x+1)\tan(x+x^2) - 2\tan(2x)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your correction, I have revised my answer.  $f(x)=\int_x^{x^2}tan(x+y)dy=ln(cos(x+x^2))-ln(cos(2x))$.  Therefore $f'(x)=(2x+1)tan(x+x^2)-2tan(2x)$.

Comment: The question is phrased in terms of $x$ and $y$, not $x$, $v$, and $y$. Not sure why @Holo edited my original post to appear that way, but I changed it back

Comment: I believe you've flipped a negative during the integration

Comment: This question can be generalized.  Let $f(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}h(c(x)+y)dy$, where $a(x),b(x),c(x),h(x)$ are all known.  Then $f(x)=H(c(x)+b(x))-H(c(x)+a(x))$ where $H(x)$ may not be explicitly representable, but $H'(x)=h(x)$.  Then $f'(x)=(c'(x)+b'(x))h(c(x)+b(x))-(c'(x)+a'(x))(h(c(x)+a(x))$.   
     The chain rule is used at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try:
\begin{align}
f'(x)
&=\partial_x \int\limits_x^{x^2}\tan(x+y)\,dy \\
&= \tan(x+ x^2) (x^2)' - \tan(x + x)(x)' + 
\int\limits_x^{x^2}\partial_x \tan(x+y)\,dy \\
&= 2x \tan(x+ x^2) - \tan(2x) + 
\int\limits_x^{x^2}(1+ \tan^2(x+y)) dy \\
&= 2x \tan(x+ x^2) - \tan(2x) +
\left[\tan(x + y) \right]_{y=x}^{y=x^2} \\
&= 2x \tan(x+x^2) - \tan(2x) + \tan(x+x^2) - \tan(2x) \\
&= (2x+1) \tan(x+x^2) - 2\tan(2x)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $$F(x,t)= \int_{0}^x \tan(t+y)dy$$

Then we have $$f(x)= F(x,x^2)-F(x,x)$$

NOTE THAT $\partial_x F(x,t) = \tan(t+x)$ and  $\partial_t F(x,t) = \tan(x+t)- \tan(t)$

can you conclude?